# How to include a user defined variable in sqldf query?

Tags: r, sqldf

I have a list of values that I want to parse through in the future. For the time being to ensure that I have the format correct for this query. I have this query:

```
var2 = "Application Maintenance"

r = fn$sqldf("Select Iteration, (SUM(Hours) / SUM(Effort)) as Efficiency
     From df WHERE Iteration = $var2") 

query = sprintf('Select Iteration, (SUM(Hours) / SUM(Effort)) 
as Efficiency from df WHERE Iteration = %s', var2)

q = sqldf(query)
```

I am getting the error in both attempts: Error in result_create(conn@ptr, statement) : 
  near "Maintenance": syntax error

I have only used sqldf once in the past so I am still new to the syntax. The query worked just fine when I changed $var2 to "Application Maintenance" but is not working when I use a user defined variable.

I've tried solutions from other Stackoverflow posts, but I kept getting the same error above.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Edit: Code for list iteration (path_list is a list of strings): getting NULL
'Error in tcltk::as.tclObj(X) : cannot handle object of mode 'list''

```
for (var1 in path_list){
  query = fn$sqldf("Select Iteration, (SUM(Hours) / SUM(Effort)) as Efficiency 
  From df WHERE Iteration = '$var1'")
  print(query)
```

}

Edit 2: The path_list is contained in this format (when clicking on the list in RStudio:

```
       Iteration
'Application Maintenance'
'Task'
'QA'
```

Edit 3: Included Example of first 15 rows. There are thousands in this data set. Changed 'Iteration' column names for confidentiality reasons:

[image: There are ~15 unique 'Iteration' types, this captures first 15 rows]

Comment: what is your `path_list` ?  Is it a `list` In that case you have to use `[[` for extraction

Comment: @akrun Yes this is a list of characters. Where would I use the [[ for extraction? I was using the contents as an iterator through the for loop unsure how to restructure that.

Comment: Please use a reproducible example as it becomes easier to understand where the problem is.

Comment: @akrun I have included edit. If you need more details please let me know. The list contains those values and some.

Comment: It is not clear whether it is a `data.frame` or `list` or not.  If you notice my post, I have used an example where you can test it.

Comment: @akrun It is of type data.frame. Could that be why your code doesn't run properly when I put it in a loop? It didn't work when I converted it to a list either.

Comment: If `pathList <- data.frame(Iteration = c('a', 'b', 'c')` Then you need `pathList$Iteration`

Comment: @akrun So following up on this. I should convert pathList to this before loading it into the for loop? It is of type data.frame already. Should I change that again?

Comment: As I mentioned earlier, it is difficult to comment without a reproducible example

Comment: How do you want me to provide that sample? I can definitely do that. The path_iteration is an identical copy of what it is on my dataset. The Hours and Effort are just integers. Please let me know.

Comment: Please check the updated post

Comment: @akrun Thanks for the post. The code is running now but it is only printing the last iteration and NA for "Efficiency". When I ran it by loading just one variable into path_list it worked. Just doesn't work in the for loop for some reason.

Comment: If you check the example i showed, it is working fine for me.  As I said earlier, you didn't showed a reproducible example

Comment: @akrun Please check edit. Let me know if you need more.

Comment: @akrun If it helps, when I call 'path_list[1]', it returns ALL of the 'Iteration' types. It should ideally return only one of the 'Iteration' types.

Comment: It is not very clear to me.  I showed an example that you can copy/paste and run it, but you are not providing the same\

Comment: @akrun All I had to do was transpose the list in which I held 'Iteration'. Thank you again. Your solution worked great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can wrap the `$var` in a single quote

```
library(sqldf)
fn$sqldf("Select Iteration, (SUM(Hours) / SUM(Effort)) as Efficiency
 From df WHERE Iteration = '$var2'")
```

Using a reproducible example

```
fn$sqldf("select cyl, (sum(hp)/sum(wt)) as Efficiency from mtcars where new = '$var2'")
#    cyl Efficiency
#1   6   34.21462
```

---

If we are doing this on a loop

```
path_list <- c("Mazda RX4", "Datsun 710", "Valiant")
for(var1 in path_list) print(sqldf(sprintf("select cyl, (sum(hp)/sum(wt)) as Efficiency from mtcars where new = '%s'", var1)))
#cyl Efficiency
#1   6   41.98473
#  cyl Efficiency
#1   4   40.08621
#  cyl Efficiency
#1   6   30.34682
```

#### data

```
data(mtcars)
mtcars$new <- row.names(mtcars)
var2 <- "Hornet 4 Drive"
```

Comment: That worked perfectly thank you so much. For some reason, this isn't working in the for loop I included in the edit. I used the same logic and it is giving me 'Error in tcltk::as.tclObj(X) : cannot handle object of mode 'list''.